Redis STREAM and Websocket logic issue livedata
I have this repository: https://github.com/poboisvert/vote-streamRedis-websocket/blob/main/src/checkinreceiver.js#L118
My question: I think what I did is total nonsense, but works. Is there a way to render faster the newly compile vote score after a POST? The logic is I post a vote.

The API create a key in the stream
the file checkinprocessor.js
calculate the new vote score and update the database
the checkinreceiver.js return the new average score after the checkinprocessor is finished after the vote is completed to the UI.

conf.json
{
  "logLevel": "debug",
  "session": {
    "secret": "red15alltheTh1ngZ!",
    "appName": "checkinapp",
    "keyPrefix": "session"  
  },
  "application": {
    "port": 8081
  },
  "auth": {
    "port": 8083
  },
  "checkinReceiver": {
    "port": 8082,
    "maxStreamLength": 500000
  },
  "redis": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 6379,
    "password": null,
    "keyPrefix": "ncc"
  }
}

Express.js server.js is like
const config = require("better-config");
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");
const routes = require("./routes");
const logger = require("./utils/logger");
const port = config.get("application.port");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const { Server } = require("ws"); // Importing the 'ws' package
const { createServer } = require("http"); // you can use https as well

const pgClient = require("./utils/db"); // Import PostgreSQL client

// Load the configuration
config.set(`../${process.env.CRASH_COURSE_CONFIG_FILE || "config.json"}`);

const app = express();
const server = createServer(app);

app.use(helmet());
app.use(morgan("combined", { stream: logger.stream }));
app.use(cors());
app.use("/api", routes);

app.get("/", (_, res) => {
  res.json({});
});

// Create a WebSocket server
const wss = new Server({ noServer: true });

// Handle WebSocket connection
wss.on("connection", (ws) => {
  console.log("Client connected");

  // Send the latest items to the client when they connect
  broadcastLatestItems(ws);

  // Handle incoming messages from the client
  ws.on("message", (message) => {
    console.log(`Received: ${message}`);
    // Handle messages from the client here
  });

  ws.on("close", () => {
    console.log("Client disconnected");
  });
});

// Function to broadcast latest items to all connected clients
async function broadcastLatestItems() {
  try {
    const result = await pgClient.query(
      "SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY numvotes DESC LIMIT 100"
    );
    const latestItems = JSON.stringify(result.rows);
    wss.clients.forEach((client) => {
      if (client.readyState === client.OPEN) {
        client.send(latestItems);
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error("Failed to fetch items from SQL", error);
  }
}

setInterval(broadcastLatestItems, 2000); // Send updates every 2 seconds

// Upgrade HTTP server to handle WebSocket requests
server.on("upgrade", (request, socket, head) => {
  wss.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, (ws) => {
    wss.emit("connection", ws, request);
  });
});

// Start the server
server.listen(port, () => {
  logger.info(`Application listening on port ${port}.`);
});

// Check for required environment variables.
if (process.env.WEATHER_API_KEY === undefined) {
  console.warn("Warning: Environment variable WEATHER_API_KEY is not set!");
}


The Redis API receiver is like this:
const config = require("better-config");
const express = require("express");
const { body } = require("express-validator");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");
const logger = require("./utils/logger");
const apiErrorReporter = require("./utils/apierrorreporter");

const useAuth = process.argv[2] === "auth";
const pgClient = require("./utils/db"); // Import PostgreSQL client

config.set(`../${process.env.CRASH_COURSE_CONFIG_FILE || "config.json"}`);

const redis = require("./utils/redisclient");
const session = require("express-session");
const RedisStore = require("connect-redis").default;

const redisClient = redis.getClient();
const pubsubClient = redis.getClient(); // Separate Redis client for Pub/Sub

const app = express();
app.use(morgan("combined", { stream: logger.stream }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

// Initialize store.
let redisStore = new RedisStore({
  client: redisClient,
  prefix: redis.getKeyName(`${config.session.keyPrefix}:`),
});

if (useAuth) {
  logger.info("Authentication enabled, checkins require a valid user session.");
  app.use(
    session({
      secret: config.session.secret,
      store: redisStore,
      name: config.session.appName,
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: true,
    })
  );
} else {
  logger.info(
    "Authentication disabled, checkins do not require a valid user session."
  );
}

const votesStreamKey = redis.getKeyName("votes");
const maxStreamLength = config.get("checkinReceiver.maxStreamLength");

app.post(
  "/api/checkin",
  (req, res, next) => {
    if (useAuth && !req.session.user) {
      logger.debug("Rejecting checkin - no valid user session found.");
      return res.status(401).send("Authentication required.");
    }

    return next();
  },
  [
    body().isObject(),
    body("userId").isInt({ min: 1 }),
    body("itemId").isInt({ min: 1 }),
    body("starRating").isInt({ min: 0, max: 5 }),
    apiErrorReporter,
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const vote = req.body;
    const pipeline = redisClient.pipeline();

    pipeline.xadd(
      votesStreamKey,
      "MAXLEN",
      "~",
      maxStreamLength,
      "*",
      ...Object.entries(vote).flat(),
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          logger.error("Error adding checkin to stream:");
          logger.error(err);
        } else {
          logger.debug(`Received checkin, added to stream as ${result}`);
          incomingId = result;
        }
      }
    );

    await pipeline.exec();

    // Wait for the notification from checkinprocessor.js and fetch the updated data
    try {
      const items = await waitForCheckinCompletion();
      return res.status(200).json(items);
    } catch (error) {
      logger.error("Error fetching new data:", error);
      return res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
    }
  }
);

// Pub/Sub based function to fetch new data when notified by checkinprocessor.js
async function waitForCheckinCompletion() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const pubChannel = redis.getKeyName("checkin-complete");

    // Subscribe to the Redis channel
    pubsubClient.subscribe(pubChannel);

    // Listen for published messages
    pubsubClient.on("message", async (channel, message) => {
      console.log("message", message);
      console.log("channel", channel);
      console.log("pubChannel", pubChannel);
      if (message === result) {
        try {
          // Fetch data from PostgreSQL when notification is received
          const result = await pgClient.query(
            "SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY numvotes DESC LIMIT 100"
          );
          resolve(result.rows);
        } catch (error) {
          reject(error);
        } finally {
          // Unsubscribe after receiving the message to prevent multiple triggers
          pubsubClient.unsubscribe(pubChannel);
        }
      }
    });

    // Handle errors in Redis Pub/Sub
    pubsubClient.on("error", (err) => {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
}

const port = config.get("checkinReceiver.port");
app.listen(port, () => {
  logger.info(`Checkin receiver listening on port ${port}.`);
});

The UI has a POST method in Next.js
  const upvoteItem = async (itemId: number) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8082/api/checkin", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          userId: Math.ceil(Math.random() * (5 - 1) + 1),
          itemId: itemId,
          starRating: Math.ceil(Math.random() * (4 - 0) + 0),
        }),
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Failed to upvote item");
      }

      // Parse the JSON response
      const data = await response.json();

      // Set the data (assuming setData is defined in your component)
      setData(data);

      // Optionally display modal or handle UI updates
      console.log("Upvote successful:", data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error upvoting item:", error);
    }
  };

I try to compile votes scores in REDIS STREAM but the rendering is too slow

Why do you need to fetch SQL data every pool instead of pool once, update redis with data and pool from redis, while background process just update the db? Try to not use math if you can.

I wanted to save the data into SQL to do dashboarding, but I feel I am missing something. I updated the code since I put a pubSub and it seems to work. I am new to Redis and not sure how to structure

Use Redis as the main db for fast interaction, backup data in SQL in background process (you can initiate on request, but it should run separate process so it won't slow the response). If for some reason you can't get response from redis fetch from db since if redis crash the data is lost. If you use pubsub no reason to use stream, they used for the same, pubsub can subscribe to any object you want.  You can arrange data much better in hash table or a set. Why you use pipeline if you invoke on command?

Can you explain the json usage? Im feeling im missing something

JSON is either the config.json to setup the project or the json is also used to return a json response to render in the Next.js UI

Stream is used if a service like processor is down and restart after a while there is be a queue to processor from the website. The votes are not lost

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
